# Gutenberg React - Struggling to use withSelect

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am currently building a custom block using Gutenberg, I usually use the save like this....

```
edit({attributes, setAttributes}) {

    /* Set Constants */
    const {
        mytitle,
        mycontent
    } = attributes;

    function ontitleChange(newTitle) {
        setAttributes({ title: newTitle});
    }

    return ([
         <TextControl 
            value={title}
            label="Title"
            onChange={(value) => {ontitleChange}
        />
    ])

},
```

This is working great, but now I am trying to add in a media upload that uses withSelect, all of the examples I have seen use it in this format....

```
edit: withSelect((select, props) => {
    return { media: props.attributes.mediaId ? select('core').getMedia(props.attributes.mediaId) : undefined };
})(BlockEdit),
```

How can I modify my version to suit this new code? Does anybody have an example of one written another way that is compatible?

Answer (score 3):

To extend on your existing function, you can utilise [compose](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-compose/) to wrap your existing edit function and create an enhanced component. So that your code remains mostly the same and easier to manage, take what you have as your edit() function and create a new file:

edit.js

```
import { withSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
import { compose } from '@wordpress/compose';
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';

export function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes, media }) {

    console.log(media); // media contains the returned value of applyWithSelect

    /* Set Constants */
    const {
       title,
       content
    } = attributes;

    // nb: removed function ontitleChange() in favour of directly calling setAttributes()

    return (
        <TextControl
            value={title}
            label="Title"
            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ title: value })}
        />
    )
}

const applyWithSelect = withSelect((select, props) => {
    // media is the name of the returned value
    return { media: props.attributes.mediaId ? select('core').getMedia(props.attributes.mediaId) : undefined };
});

/**
* Use compose to return the result of withSelect to Edit({...})
* @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-compose/
*/
export default compose(
    applyWithSelect,
)(Edit);
```

index.js

```
/**
* Internal dependencies
*/
import Edit from './edit';

registerBlockType('myproject/blockname', {
...
    attributes: {
    mediaId: {
        type: 'number',
        ... // other props as needed
    },
    title: {
        type: 'string',
        ... // other props as needed
    },
    content: {
        type: 'string',
        ... // other props as needed
    }
    edit: Edit, // this is now the name of exported component from edit.js
...
});
```